# Check empty struct that have array fields

Tags: arrays, go, struct, slice

I have a nested (not embedded) struct for which some of field types are arrays.

How can I check if an instance of this struct is empty? (not using iteration!!)

Note that there can't use `StructIns == (Struct{})` or by an empty instance! This code have this error:

`invalid operation: user == model.User literal (struct containing model.Configs cannot be compared)`

user.Configs.TspConfigs:

```
type TspConfigs struct {
    Flights     []Flights   `form:"flights" json:"flights"`
    Tours       []Tours     `form:"tours" json:"tours"`
    Insurances  []Insurances`form:"insurances" json:"insurances"`
    Hotels      []Hotels    `form:"hotels" json:"hotels"`
}
```

Comment: Iteration is the only possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), not [arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types). It's important to emphasize as arrays are comparable but slices are not. See [Spec: Comparision operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators). And since slices are not comparable, structs composed of them (structs with fields having slice types) are also not comparable.

You may use [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) for this. Example:

```
type Foo struct {
    A []int
    B []string
}

f := Foo{}
fmt.Println("Zero:", reflect.DeepEqual(f, Foo{}))
f.A = []int{1}
fmt.Println("Zero:", reflect.DeepEqual(f, Foo{}))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qQSydTe4uk)):

```
Zero: true
Zero: false
```

Comment: I have used a package from github called deep or Deep which has a method similar to reflect.DeepEqual(), which also identifies the first non-equal component.